# Developement platform for j2EE/Flex under linux?

Tags: linux, apache-flex, compatibility

At work we run vista for all the laptop. 
I dont like it very much.
XP is not an option because of licence ( and money ) issues.
The boss and the team is ok to whatever, since the work is done.

So i wish to switch my developement plateform to a linux ( i dont care wich one ).

Problem : we are building something in Adobe Flex. And i'v read a lots of bad thing for the couple flex / linux.

My Question : can i develop without huge constraint a Flex/J2EE Application under linux, using eclipse, and the flexbuilder plugin. ( Or at least eclipse + flexSDK compiler )

thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [AXDT](http://axdt.org/) plugin for a gratis alternative to FlexBuilder.

Comment: seems nice, i will give it a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I develop on Linux but have a virtual box instance just encase I need to use windows for something for work. Works really well :-)